# Validating an HDF5 superblock checksum

Tags: hdf5, netcdf

I am having a problem writing a program which verifies the checksum in the superblock of an HDF5, Version 2 file. I am not using the HDF5 software, but I have a copy of H5_checksum_fletcher32 (from the HDF5 H5checksum.c) in my code.

I can assume that the file signature block is at position 0.

My logic is:

```
Let offset = the value of byte 9 of the file.

The superblock spans bytes 0 to (15+4*offset). 

The last 4 bytes are the checksum as an unsigned int.

The checksum should equal H5_checksum_fletcher32 applied to bytes 0 to (11+4*offset).
```

I have applied this logic to several test files from NOAA that I believe to be reliable, but the checksum never matches the result of H5_checksum_fletcher32. The other values in the superblock appear to be correct. Can anyone see the flaw in my logic?

Comment: I assume you're counting from 0, as the offset is tenth byte of the superblock. Also, if you're just trying to check if a file is valid, there is [h5check](http://www.hdfgroup.org/products/hdf5_tools/h5check.html).

Answer (score 1):

From the [HDF5 file format specification](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.format.html#Intro):

> All checksums used in the format are computed with the [Jenkins' lookup3](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html) algorithm.

This is provided in `H5checksum.c` as `H5_checksum_lookup3()`.

Actually, it seems the correct routine to call is `H5_checksum_metadata()`, but this just calls `H5_checksum_lookup3()` using a macro.